# Treeview How to save a value

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

How do I save off a value on treenode? I am using C# Windows forms framework 4.0.  Is the Tag the only place to save off a value?  I need to save off the window name in order to open the window when the user clicks on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need more than one value to store in the tree node then the best way is to extend `TreeNode` by inherent your class from it, and use your own tree node.

```
public class YourTreeNode : TreeNode
{
    public string WindowName { get; set; }
}
```

Or just the tag and store the windowname in the name.